# How to link python's static library for C extensions?

Tags: python, c++, linker, python-c-extension

I am trying to write an C++ extension for python which involves Python C API. According to my previous experience on doing this with Visual Studio, I just need to include python's header files and link python's static libraries and everything would work fine.

However I couldn't do this on OS X Mavericks now. I installed a separate Python 3.4.2 from python.org and added an include entry in my Cmake configuration:
`include_directories("/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/Headers")`

Then I have no clue how to proceed with the static libraries part. On Windows they are stored in `%python_root%/libs` and you can find `.lib` files there. But on OS X I couldn't find such directory in which `.a` static libraries are placed.

I tried several solutions such as attaching the result of `python-config --lib` to compile options and `set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)` while they all ended up with the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
    "_PyLong_FromLong", referenced from:
        test() in Main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I tried `distutils` as well, but it didn't seem to work properly, either :(

Comment: *Where* did you set the flags/libraries returned by `python-config --libs`? To which variable? Because those flags are *linker* flags and not compiler flags.

Comment: I set them to `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` in `cmake.txt` and the result returned was like `-ldl -framework CoreFoundation -lpython3.4m`.

Comment: Adding libraries to the compiler flags doesn't help, as those are only used for compilation, you should add them to e.g. `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS` instead. Then they will also be added in the correct place on the linker command line (where order of object/source files and libraries matter).

Comment: Thanks. I added `CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS` entry and also the `LINK_DIRECTORIES` pointing at the static library path and it now works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting a linker error,  the library is has not been added to your link options.

On my system OSX 10.8.5,  the static library is in the directory below:
You need to add the directory to your cmake library path, and and add the python library itself.  (In GCC you use the -L and -l options).

```
Directory: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/config/

file: libpython2.7.a
```

Comment: Thanks and it works now :) I thought that the static library directory would contain many `.a` files as it did on Windows but things are quite different here.